# How can I query for a specific value within an array that exists in a mongo document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I have a bunch of documents inside a mongodb collection with the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "ddksdk"
  },
"date": {"$date": { "$numberLong": "1627862400000"}
},
"prices": [{"_id": {"$oid": "ddks11"}, "inventoryCode": "JFXS", "price": 52},
           {"_id": {"$oid": "ddks12"}, "inventoryCode": "USSW", "price": 102}]
}
```

I was looking forward to set an statement in order to obtain the document with a specifc date , and within that `date` I was looking forward to filter by an `inventoryCode` within the array of `prices` to obtain as an output the object filtered by date and inventoryCode.

The query I tried goes as follows:

```
{
  $and: [
    {
      date: { $eq: "2021-08-02T00:00:00.000+00:00") },
    },
    {
      prices: {
        $elemMatch: {
          inventoryCode: { $eq: "USSW" },
        },
      },
    },
  ],
}
```

with this statement I am actually filtering by date , obtaining the corresponding doc with that particular date but i am not filtering within the array by the specific `inventoryCode` . How could I achieve this?

The expected output i would like to receive is :

```
{"_id": {"$oid": "ddks12"}, "inventoryCode": "USSW", "price": 102}
```

Comment: Just updated to include the expected output

Comment: ok but what will happen if there is more than 1 USSW in the prices array? or this can never happen?

Comment: inventoryCode is unique within each doc

Comment: ok i updated the answer i think it does what you need, match date, filter invetory code, keeps the doc if invetory was found, and replaces the root with the found array member.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

- keeps the documents with the specific date
- filter to keep only those with `inventoryCode= USSW`
- keeps the documents where prices is not empty
- replace the root with the first member of prices
  (to get the expected output)
- to be fast add a index on date id you don't have

[Playmongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=63af02dc3601f685eed54a8b)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match":{"$expr":{"$eq":["$date", ISODate("2021-08-02T00:00:00Z")]}}},
 {"$set":
   {"prices":
     {"$filter":
       {"input":"$prices",
        "cond":{"$eq":["$$this.inventoryCode", "USSW"]}}}}},
 {"$match":{"$expr":{"$ne":["$prices", []]}}},
 {"$replaceRoot":{"newRoot":{"$first":"$prices"}}}])
```

Comment: will the set  modify the document in the db?

Comment: you want update? like change the document inside the db? its easy to change if you want update. this is not update, you just query, `$set` is alias of `$addfields`

Comment: No no I dont want any changes within the db just a read req without any changes , jic wanted to make sure , ill try it out